# 'Undefined variable' error when returning an array from a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

Essentially, I have a message class with a function that can write to an array. I want to then return that instance of an array through a function when called.

This is the class:

```
class Message
{
    public $formMessages = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function writeFormMessage($field, $message)
    {
        $formMessages[$field] = $message;
    }

    public function getFormMessages()
    {
        return $this->formMessages;
    }
}
```

Here is how I am attempting to grab the formMessages array from another file. Yes I already have an instance of the Message class in said file.

```
$test = $message->getFormMessages();
```

It fails this predicate, though it doesn't seem to be seeing the array anyhow:

```
if (!empty($test))
{ 
}
```

The php error was 'Undefined variable: formMessages in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\message.class.php on line 45'

**Edit**: Thanks all!

Comment: ...what's your question? What part doesn't work? Your question is unclear.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($test);` ?

Comment: @ Jeremy, I'm receiving this error: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: formMessages in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\message.class.php on line 45. Thanks.

Comment: `formErrors` isn't even in your posted code. Show us what/how you're using this.

Comment: @Error-404: Your posted code doesn't have any `$formErrors` so how's that error any surprise?

Comment: You've got to specify that in your post.

Comment: Long Story short: Your posted code is fine, it's either how you use it or you're not posting the actual code. Also: If you're posting errors be sure to tell us exactly what line of code it is... your paste doesn't contain 45 lines.

Comment: Sorry guys have amended. CP'd in error. This is the code. Will check the var dump now, thanks.

Comment: You need to access `$formMessages` through `$this->formMessages`. Take a look: http://ideone.com/wUCfkT (check my line 12 and compare to yours)

Comment: @ Jeremy, ahh that worked. Thanks! Thank you to everyone else as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line in your `writeFormMessage` method:

```
$formMessages[$field] = $message;
```

That attempts to access a local variable. (Which doesn't exist within that method.)

Compare to this usage in `getFormMessages()` however:

```
return $this->formMessages;
```

There you are correctly accessing the intended property.

Use the same `$this->` syntax for both.

Comment: **Thank you** for making this a community. Too many rep-leeching users -- even high-rep ones who should know by now -- that post answers like this non-wiki (see @1nflktd below for ref).

Comment: @Jeremy Actually, the other answer was put up before this one was put up. Both may have been typing out the same or similar answer at the very same time. Since your comment led to an answer, you also had the opportunity to have put in an answer of your own.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This one was posted 6 minutes ago, the below 5 minutes.

Comment: @Jeremy This one `2:35:16` - the other one `2:35:34` look at the timestamps. I doubt very much that the other answer copied on this one and/or your comment within an 18 second period.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Where are you getting these timestamps from?

Comment: @Jeremy Place your mouse over "answered X minutes ago" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- What's your point anyway? All I'm saying is that posts like these should be community wikis... Too many people post 3 line responses and want rep (hey, I used to do it...)

Comment: @Jeremy My point is; if answers are to be given in order to mark a question as solved, then answers are given, correct? The other person gave an answer, as did Mario. Mario; decided on a wiki, because that was his choice. Mario has enough rep points and has already proven his competence a long time ago. Give the other guy a break. If it will add to his/her credibility and integrity as a community member, then that person stands at being trusted when giving answers, which hopefully will lead to a solution and that's what it's all about, finding solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function writeFormMessage($field, $message)
{
    $formMessages[$field] = $message;
}

public function getFormMessages()
{
    return $this->formMessages;
}
```

You are saying different things here, that's why you got empty from the result.
You think you are refering to the same var, but you are not. `$formMessages` is a variable that exists only inside the `WriteFormMessage` function while `$this->formMessages` exists outside it.

Then you have to reference it with `$this` to get proper results.

```
    $this->formMessages[$field] = $message;
```

Comment: Thanks 1nflktd and Mario/Jeremy, appreciated. The clarification helped greatly.